# Why is HtmlAgilityPack SelectSingleNode not finding divs

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack, selectsinglenode

On the real world C# script I tried every permutation (although hopefully someone will tell me I have missed one) that I understand to be viable for the XPath value, but always returning null. Striped it back to what would seem to be the simplest use of `SelectSingleNode` but still for some reason it will only return a value with `<body>`

Doc assigned thus:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
```

This is the first time I have looked into XPath and I have had limited experience with HtmlAgilityPack. So it's no doubt a very basic failing on my part. However:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
```

result: node is not null

replacing it with div or any other element (that ARE in the script-tested more than one)

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div");
```

Result:

> node is null

What have I missed?

Comment: Your syntax for finding a div tag is correct.  IF the result is null, that means there are no div tags in the html document.

Comment: Yes indeed, however as I said these tags are in the script, and it is returning null. So what might cause it to fail? Example script that I used to the code code can be found on adventurebods.com/home/

Comment: In fact your correct broke hence adding an answer to this myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry my bad - got to the bottom of this. Whilst the example at the adventurebods URL above was the source of the intended test script, it transpires in fact I have something less. The process preceding this requirement copies from the clipboard the script - and of course being a lemon I had assumed this to be correct but in fact I have a truncated script after using:

```
htmlText = Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Html);
```